# Is "soliciting" in the example sentence an adjective or a noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives

In the following sentence, I would like to understand if the word "soliciting"  is a noun or an adjective.

"Is my reluctance that soliciting?"

Here, the word "soliciting" appears to be a kind of noun, as in the state of soliciting. However, it also appears to be adjectival as it describes the subject of the sentence, which is the word reluctance.

Furthermore, what would be the specific name of this word - is it a "verbal noun" or a "participle" etc.

Comment: I am trying to identify what that word, or any similar transitive verb (such as solicit, elicit, etc), would be called in the context of the sentence in the example. The sentence doesn't necessarily have to be this exact sentence.

Comment: The main problem is that the sentence provides no context.  The word is behaving as an adjective on "reluctance", but what "soliciting reluctance" is supposed mean is hard to guess.

Comment: My best guess is that it's an adjective. Why? If you were to replace the word "soliciting" with a word such as "annoying", then it would be quite obvious that the sentence ends with a description of the subject's reluctance: _Is my reluctance that annoying?_

Comment: @WindowsDude7: Saying "If you replace the word with an adjective it becomes clear it should be an adjective" is special pleading. I would agree with you,but for the fact that *soliciting* is not an adjective in normal dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, it is an adjective: only an adjective (or adverb) can follow *that* in this sense (= 'so', or 'as *xxx* as that').

But like Hot Licks, I can barely understand what it is supposed to mean, because *soliciting* as a description of an attitude or mental state makes no sense to me. I guess it is supposed to mean *attractive* or *appealing*, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If the sentence were written as "Is my reluctance that appealing?" would "appealing" be an adjective, or would "that appealing" be considered a noun? As in, the state of being appealing. I'm trying to understand for certain that it is not some kind of noun or gerund of some kind, and is in fact an adjective?

Comment: Yes, it would certainly be an adjective, because it is qualified as "that" (in that sense).